# One slider to control graphs in single subplot in R using plotly

Tags: r, plotly, dygraphs, r-plotly

I'm looking for certain fix with range selector in plotly using R.
I have two plots visualized via a single subplot using Plotly in R. Now, I need to add a Range Slider/Selector to the complete plot, so that changing it modifies both my plots.
Is it possible via **Plotly**? (using R only)
This functionality is similar to **Dygraphs** synchronize feature(https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-synchronization.html).

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using `subplot`s option `shareX = TRUE`:

Please check the following example:

```
library(plotly)

DF1 <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=runif(100)+ seq(0, 1, length.out = 100))
DF2 <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=runif(100)+ seq(0, 2, length.out = 100))

p1 <- plot_ly(DF1, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers")
p2 <- plot_ly(DF2, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers")

p <- subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE)
p
```

[image: Result]

Comment: For future readers: At the bottom of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70953812/9841389) you can find a related approach using a rangeslider.