# how to dynamically change plotly axis based on crosstalk conditions

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, crosstalk

This question has [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242422/set-dynamic-axis-limits-with-crosstalk), but didn't get an answer since it didn't have a reprex, so let me give it a go.

Lets say I have two datasets that span different date ranges. I want to control the visualization of each using a slider. The following reprex will create the visual directly below.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

#+ message = FALSE, warning = FALSE
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(dplyr)
#+
```

```{r}
df1 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "months", length.out = 100), v = runif(100))
df2 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-6-01"), by = "months", length.out = 20), other_v = runif(20))

both_df <- full_join(df1, df2, by = 'd')

both_df_sh <- both_df %>% SharedData$new(group = "boom")

selector <- filter_slider(id = "selector1", label = "select dates", sharedData = both_df_sh, column = ~d)

v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~v, name = "v", color = I("blue"))

other_v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~other_v, name = "other v", color = I("red"))
```

```{r}
crosstalk::bscols(v_p, other_v_p)
```
````

[image]

This is correct since both charts show their date ranges correctly. However, my client would like to see blanks in charts if no data exists for that range. Something like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

#+ message = FALSE, warning = FALSE
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(dplyr)
#+
```

```{r}
df1 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "months", length.out = 100), v = runif(100))
df2 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-6-01"), by = "months", length.out = 20), other_v = runif(20))

both_df <- full_join(df1, df2, by = 'd')

both_df_sh <- both_df %>% SharedData$new(group = "boom")

selector <- filter_slider(id = "selector1", label = "select dates", sharedData = both_df_sh, column = ~d)

v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~v, name = "v", color = I("blue")) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(range = list(min(both_df_sh$data()$d, na.rm = TRUE), 
                            max(both_df_sh$data()$d, na.rm = TRUE))))

other_v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~other_v, name = "other v", color = I("red")) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(range = list(min(both_df_sh$data()$d, na.rm = TRUE), 
                            max(both_df_sh$data()$d, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

```{r}
selector
```

```{r}
crosstalk::bscols(v_p, other_v_p)
```
````

Which gives us, as expected, this:
[image]

Which is what I wanted! However, now, the chart no longer scales with the `filter_select`, it only hides the data, which doesn't create lovely visuals:
[image]

So, I would want the chart limit to "skootch over" as the bar is dragged... but to do that I need the value of the `filter_select` at the time.

I thought I could get it beforehand by changing the limits like this:

```
selector_values <- jsonlite::fromJSON(selector$children[[3]]$children[[1]])$values

v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~v, name = "v", color = I("blue")) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(range = min(selector_values), max(selector_values)))

other_v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~other_v, name = "other v", color = I("red")) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(range = min(selector_values), max(selector_values)))
```

but those values don't get re-evaluated after the dashboard is launched. I need a way to access the CURRENT value of those selectors... how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use plotly's `matches` parameter to align the axes of multiple plots just as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70837051/plotly-sharex-between-side-by-side-plots/70845814#70845814):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

#+ message = FALSE, warning = FALSE
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(dplyr)
#+
```

```{r}
df1 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "months", length.out = 100), v = runif(100))
df2 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-6-01"), by = "months", length.out = 20), other_v = runif(20))

both_df <- full_join(df1, df2, by = 'd')

both_df_sh <- both_df %>% SharedData$new(group = "boom")

selector <- filter_slider(id = "selector1", label = "select dates", sharedData = both_df_sh, column = ~d)

v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~v, name = "v", color = I("blue"))

other_v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~other_v, name = "other v", color = I("red")) %>% layout(xaxis = list(matches = "x"))
```

```{r}
selector
```

```{r, out.width='100%'}
subplot(v_p, other_v_p, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)
```
````

[image: result]

---

**Original answer:**

I'm not sure if I understand your expected output correctly but if you want to autoscale the x-axes just remove the xaxis `range` (the `layout()` call). `crosstalk` will take care about providing the filtered data based on the `filter_slider`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

#+ message = FALSE, warning = FALSE
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(dplyr)
#+
```

```{r}
df1 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "months", length.out = 100), v = runif(100))
df2 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-6-01"), by = "months", length.out = 20), other_v = runif(20))

both_df <- full_join(df1, df2, by = 'd')

both_df_sh <- both_df %>% SharedData$new(group = "boom")

selector <- filter_slider(id = "selector1", label = "select dates", sharedData = both_df_sh, column = ~d)

v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~v, name = "v", color = I("blue"))

other_v_p <- both_df_sh %>% plot_ly(x = ~d) %>% add_lines(y = ~other_v, name = "other v", color = I("red"))
```

```{r}
selector
```

```{r}
crosstalk::bscols(v_p, other_v_p)
```
````

### [image: result]

A non-crosstalk approach, using a shared x-axis and a rangeslider:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "months", length.out = 100), v = runif(100))
df2 <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-6-01"), by = "months", length.out = 20), other_v = runif(20))

both_df <- full_join(df1, df2, by = 'd')

fig1 <- plot_ly(both_df, x = ~ d, y = ~ v, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
fig2 <- plot_ly(both_df, x = ~ d, y = ~ other_v, type = "scatter", mode = "lines") 

fig_shared_x <- subplot(fig1, fig2, nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE)
fig_shared_x

fig_rangeslider <- fig_shared_x %>% layout(xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(type = "date")))
fig_rangeslider
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for attempt. The problem is that auto-scaling makes the x-axis labels inconsistent when the visual starts. If you take a look, the right visual includes months, and the other does not. Also, it's a bit "dishonest" because the time-scales are different and we want to make sure to visualize that difference... until it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Hi there, I think showing every month in the left plot won't look good. The rest of the behaviour is as intended?

Comment: It's the opposite. I want the right to start compressed as in my post. But then, as the slider brings the chart on the left into the same range as the right, the right chart should start expanding on the x-axis

Comment: @AmitKohli I think I understand it now. Please see my edit using the xaxis parameter `matches` (top of my post)

Comment: does that rangslider not work in ploly? It looks goregous!

Comment: Sure - the rangeslider will also work in a RMarkdown document. I just wanted to reduce the code.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. I think that the heavy lifting for this new method is being done by the `subplot`, which is consistent with the example I posted. But in my real-world example, the dashboard has multiple entities on a flex-dashboard, and for stylistic reasons each needs its own "box"... How could I do exactly what you want, but without using `subplot`?

Comment: I guess without `subplot` you'll need to write some custom JS. You could use [Plotly.relayout](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrelayout) to sync the axes and pass the JS code to the plotly object via `htmlwidgets::onRender` (see [this](https://plotly-r.com/js-event-handlers.html)). However, there is quite some work to do just to maintain a certain style.

Comment: Sounds more trouble than it's wortrh. Thanks for answering! The problem is that I have multiple charts (8), each with their own legends... I want them to share x,  and have titles and whatnot. I could use your approach and just not `inherit y`, but I think it's more trouble than it's worth for now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes - everything is a little more difficult using standalone HTML files (in a `shiny` context things would be easier). Regarding the titles check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182646/formatting-shiny-plotly-subplots-individual-titles-and-graph-size/59191142#59191142) (also working without shiny).